# Using the inverse function theorem, show that the system of nonlinear equation has a unique solution for sufficiently small $a$ and $b$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-system

Consider system of nonlinear equations:
\begin{align}
2x+xy-y &= a \\
x+4y-y^3+x^2 &=b
\end{align}
Using the inverse function theorem, show that the function has a unique solution for sufficiently small $a$ and $b$.

---

Attempt: I have not gone through the implicit function theorem yet, so here goes. We wish to show that the Jacobian determinant is nonzero at points $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $F(x_0,y_0)=(a,b)$, then by the inverse function theorem, it is one-to-one.

Computing the Jacobian determinant,
$$ \det \left(
\begin{bmatrix}
2+y & x-1 \\
1+2x & 4-3y^2
\end{bmatrix} \right)
=-3y^3-6y^2+4y+1-2x^2 + x + 9
$$
I'm not really sure where to go from here, and how to find $(x_0,y_0);F(x_0,y_0)=(a,b)$ or quite frankly if this is the correct approach. Any input would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: $F(0,0)=(0,0)$. Check that $\det DF_{(0,0)}\neq 0$. This verifies the hypotheses of the IFT. What is the conclusion of the IFT? Therefore...

Comment: @peek-a-boo why do you consider point $(0,0)$?

Comment: because it is a point where I can easily evaluate $F$ and it's derivative. And more to the point, the question asks you to (locally) invert the system of equations in the situation that $a, b$ are small. This means we wish to conside the case $(a, b)$ is close to $(0,0)$ in the target space. So, I ask myself, at which points does $F$ vanish? If I find such points then I have a chance of applying the IFT, and it turns out F vanishes at the origin.

Comment: @peek-a-boo so we should try (for similar questions where it is stated $(a,b)$ are sufficently small) to solve for the system $F(x,y)=(0,0)$ then check for a nonzero Jacobian, apply IVT to that point and we will more or less be done (after some more formalia, but this should be the general approach)?

Comment: Yes exactly. Here, we were lucky that F clearly vanishes at the origin, and has non-vanishing Jacobian determinant there, so computations were simple. For example, in 1 dimension, if $F(x)=x(x-1)^2$, then $F$ vanishes at $x=0,1$, but it is only at the origin where the derivative is non-zero so it is invertible near the origin, but not near $x=1$ (as you can easily verify by sketching this cubic function).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Great! Thanks a bunch :)